# Extract date using REGEXEXTRACT by using Google SHeets formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R_Sh72JBsJJvspUumLR-96IGsT84JxFI5WHdr2kc8H4/copy

[image]

I would like to extract date as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
and also as DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS

I have tried with

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,":?(^[0-9]+)/")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
=arrayformula(if(len(A2:A),--substitute(A2:A,",",""),))
```

and within `Formatting` > `Custom number format` use either

`yyyy"-"m"-"d" "h":"mm":"s am/pm`  OR `yyyy"-"m"-"d" "h":"mm":"s`

[image]